# How to get correct format json in spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm using RestTemplate and JSONObject to get data from db and send post to server
My service:

```
List<MyMap> customerList = customerService.getAllCustomerViewBasicInfo(params);
```

customerList will get all data from database

My Controller:

```
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    ja.put(customerList);

    JSONObject obmain1 = new JSONObject();
    obmain1.put("actionType", "update-contact");
    obmain1.accumulate("data", ja);

    JSONArray jomain1 = new JSONArray();
    jomain1.put(obmain1);

    JSONObject jomain = new JSONObject();
    jomain.put("userSender", "myemail@gmail.com");
    jomain.put("data", jomain1);

    System.out.println(jomain);
```

When I get data it have result following as: (wrong format)

```
{
  "userSender": "myemail.com",
  "data": [
  {
    "actionType": "update-contact",
    "data": [
      [
        [
        {
          "name": "TEST",
          "lastname": "TESTER",
          "phones": "0165458852",
          "addresses": "TEST",
          "passport": "870402152364",
          "customerType": "company"
        },
        {
          "name": "TEST",
          "lastname": "TESTER1",
          "phones": "0165458852",
          "passport": "870402152364",
          "customerType": "company"
        }
        ]
       ]
     ]
     }
    ]
   }
```

but it is wrong format...

and I want to get correct format and expect following as: (correct format)

```
{
"senderUser": "myemail.com",
"data": [
    {
        "actionType": "update-contact",
        "data": {
            "name": "LƯƠNG BẢO  ",
            "lastname": "LONG",
            "type": 0,
            "title": "ms",
            "passport": "123123",
            "gender": 1,
            "dateOfBirth": "03-01-2021",
            "emails": [
                {
                    "value": "myemail.com"
                }
            ],
            "phones": [
                {
                    "value": "0902032618"
                }
            ],
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "addressDetail": "osaka",
                    "street": "36 osaka",
                    "city": "Tokio",
                    "state": "Tokio",
                    "country": {
                        "code": "JP",
                        "name": "japan"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "cusFields": [
                {
                    "600f9cb0f02f084bd8a3dcdb": "TEST"
                },
                {
                    "600fbc6ef02f084bd8a3f7bd": "TEST2"
                },
                {
                    "600fbc6ef02f084bd8a3f7be": "TEST3"
                }
            ],
            "customerType": "company",
            "600f9cb0f02f084bd8a3dcdb": "SME"
        }
    }
]
}
```

How can I get correct data as expect? many thank

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your customersList list, the emails, phones and addresses attributes must be of type list of objects, if they are not, before make the json serialization you must do it, splitting the string by the separator character like comma.

Once you have done this, the code you should use is

```
List<JSONObject> jsonList = customerList.stream().map( cust -> {
       JSONObject obmain1 = new JSONObject();
       obmain1.put("actionType", "update-contact");
       obmain1.accumulate("data", cust);
  }).collect(Collectors.toList())

JSONObject jomain = new JSONObject();
    jomain.put("userSender", "myemail@gmail.com");
    jomain.put("data", jsonList);
```

Comment: Hi, i wish you can be more detail ^^

Comment: detail in which part? when I say that the emails phones and addresses must be of type list?

Comment: Yess i got it, i will try

Comment: Hi @JArgente could you give me example of email, addresses, and phones ?